# Qt5 migration: Cannot open include file: 'qtconcurrentexception.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm migrating a project to Qt5, and I'm getting this error (it compiles fine for Qt4):

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'qtconcurrentexception.h': No such file or directory
```

for this line:

```
#include <qtconcurrentexception.h>
```

I include this file in order to use `QtConcurrent::Exception`. Has the header file for `QtConcurrent::Exception` changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the below applies to Qt 5 only.

If you ever need an include of the form `<QtModule/QHeader>`, it means that you did not add the relevant Qt module to your project file. You will get linking errors later, even though such hacked include seems to work during compilation.

`QtConcurrent::Exception` is deprecated and simply forwards to `QException` from the core module. So:

```
#include <QException>
```

If you wish to use the concurrent module for something else in Qt 5, you should `#include <QtConcurrent>`. You should also add `Qt += concurrent` to your project file, and re-run qmake.